# Tailwind's gird layout with column 2 results in a vertical layout

Tags: vuejs3, tailwind-css

I have confirmed I am Tailwind is correctly installed, but for some reason I am unable to get grid layout to work.

```
<template>
<div>
    <div class="w-full md:w-3/5 p-4">
        <div class="grid grid-cols-2 md:grid-cols-2 lg:grid-cols-1 col-gap-2 md:col-gap-8 md:row-gap-10"
             v-for="c in 4">
            <Course title="The G Course"
                    description="A crash course!"
                    lessons="3"
                    length="1 hr"/>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
</template>
```

tailwind.config.js

```
module.exports = {
  content: [
    "./index.html",
    "./src/**/*.{vue,js,ts,jsx,tsx}",
  ],
  theme: {
    extend: {
      colors: {
        gray: '#111827',
        white: '#d9e6eb',
        'light-gray': '#182236',
        yellow: '#ffd859',
        'dark-yellow': '#f7d336'

      },
    },
  },
  plugins: [],
}
```

The result of the output is a vertical layout.

Any advice would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

You may have the `v-for` directive on the wrong element. Currently, the component would end up rendering HTML like:

```html
<div>
    <div class="w-full md:w-3/5 p-4">
        <div class="grid grid-cols-2 md:grid-cols-2 lg:grid-cols-1 col-gap-2 md:col-gap-8 md:row-gap-10">
           <!-- Course -->
        </div>
        <div class="grid grid-cols-2 md:grid-cols-2 lg:grid-cols-1 col-gap-2 md:col-gap-8 md:row-gap-10">
           <!-- Course -->
        </div>
        <div class="grid grid-cols-2 md:grid-cols-2 lg:grid-cols-1 col-gap-2 md:col-gap-8 md:row-gap-10">
           <!-- Course -->
        </div>
        <div class="grid grid-cols-2 md:grid-cols-2 lg:grid-cols-1 col-gap-2 md:col-gap-8 md:row-gap-10">
           <!-- Course -->
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Whereas, to have the elements *inside* the grid be looped, you'd do something like:

```js
<template>
<div>
    <div class="w-full md:w-3/5 p-4">
        <div class="grid grid-cols-2 md:grid-cols-2 lg:grid-cols-1 col-gap-2 md:col-gap-8 md:row-gap-10">
            <Course title="The G Course"
                    description="A crash course!"
                    lessons="3"
                    length="1 hr"
                    v-for="c in 4"/>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
</template>
```

Which would end up with HTML like:

```html
<div>
    <div class="w-full md:w-3/5 p-4">
        <div class="grid grid-cols-2 md:grid-cols-2 lg:grid-cols-1 col-gap-2 md:col-gap-8 md:row-gap-10">
           <!-- Course -->
           <!-- Course -->
           <!-- Course -->
           <!-- Course -->
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: thank you for posting... Sadly this did not work either.

Comment: Could you clarify how it does not work? Perhaps ensure you are viewing the webpage where the viewport is less than `1024px` width. Also consider checking the file that the code is in is covered by the `content` file globs.

Comment: I manipulated it by adjusting the screen size. I changed the html in the component to a div box which can be found here https://tailwindcss.com/docs/box-sizing to make sure the component was not the issue. Same behavior.

Answer (score 0):

```
<template>
<div class="grid grid-cols-2 w-full md:w-4/5 p-4">
    <div class="md:grid-cols-2 lg:grid-cols-1 col-gap-2 md:col-gap-8 md:row-gap-10" v-for="c in 4">
        <Course title="The Course"
                description="A crash course!"
                lessons="3"
                length="4 hr"
        />
    </div>
</div>
```

I had to move the grid to the other div and the `md` and `lg` to the other div